# Valid year function in python

Tags: python

Here is the udacity.com web dev course, they ask to write a program for valid year, anything between 1900 and 2020 is a valid year...Now when I submit my below code it gives this error:

"Incorrect. Your submission did not return the correct result for the input '1920',. Your submission passed 7 out of 9 test cases."

my function:

```
def valid_year(year):
  if year and year.isdigit():
    if int(year) >=1900 and int(year) <=2020:
      return year

print valid_year('1970')
```

why it's not working for 1920? and the same function by udacity runs fine....Someone pls tell me what's the difference b/n both the code

Udacity function:

```
def valid_year(year):
  if year and year.isdigit():
    year = int(year)
    if year >=1900 and year <=2020:
      return year

print valid_year('1970')
```

Comment: Both work fine for me, but you should return `int(year)` in your example.

Comment: they are working fine for me. python2.7

Comment: Your function returns the year as a string, udacity's returns it as an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return an `int`, because the udacity's function returns an integer:

```
def valid_year(year):
  if year and year.isdigit():
    if int(year) >=1900 and int(year) <=2020:
      return year

def valid_year_uda(year):
  if year and year.isdigit():
    year = int(year)
    if year >=1900 and year <=2020:
      return year

print valid_year('1970') == valid_year_uda('1970')
print type(valid_year('1970')), type(valid_year_uda('1970'))
```

**output:**

```
False
<type 'str'> <type 'int'>
```

This can be fixed easily just replace `return year` with `return int(year)`:

```
def valid_year(year):
  if year and year.isdigit():
    if int(year) >=1900 and int(year) <=2020:
      return int(year)  #return an integer

print valid_year('1970')
```

Comment: Interesting then how 7/9 test cases pass... Either none or all I would have thought

Comment: @JonClements Can't say about that without seeing the test cases.